# Bug: `UITextField.appearance().tintColor` changes `rightBarButtonItem` color

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know why, but this line

`UITextField.appearance().tintColor = Colors.orange`

Makes my `rightBarButtonItem` blue... (it's also set to orange somewhere else in code).

I did confirm that commenting that line makes the `rightBarButtonItem` orange as I'd expect.

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, with no code or context. People can't reason on such questions and thus will downvote it.

Comment: I'm not sure what's missing, with the line `UITextField.appearance().tintColor = Colors.orange` right button on the navigation bar is blue, without it, it's the image's color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking your code its difficult to find out. But you can try another approach add `navigation item` using attribute inspector inside your `viewcontroller` and then add `barbuttonitem` on right and add `button` inside it and then change the color whatever you required.

Comment: The rest of the code is the storyboard, with the right button with an image. What other could should I share to make the question more clear?

Comment: Btw, I think adding a UIButton inside the UIBarButtonItem might work, since the left button is set like that and the color didn't change. but still, the other way should also work, what does `UITextField` appearance have to do with any of this?

Comment: Yeah, I'll accept your answer because it did work, thank you, but I'd still like to know why the other way doesn't.